# Improving Windows Batch Script

Tags: search, batch-file, windows-server-2003

The following script search thru a folder and its sub-folders and then compares each file it gets to files in the 2nd folder. If found it echo's a message to say that the file was found.

My question is how do I enhance this script to search the 2nd folder and its sub-folders for the file found in 1st dir? I only care about the file-name with extension (I do not care in which folder/sub-folder it was found, just that a duplicate file is present and causing compiler errors)

I thought one of the ways would be to output all file names to a file and then take the file as input in 2nd part and loop thru the 2nd folder, but I am sure there must be a cleaner way.

O/S: Windows 2003

```
:bof
    rem @echo off
    cls
    setlocal
:init
    set dirA=X:\tst\pfsrc\
    set dirB=X:\tst\cbsrc\
    if not exist "%dirA%" echo dirA not found & goto :EOF
    if not exist "%dirB%" echo dirB not found & goto :EOF
    for /f "delims=" %%I in ('dir /b /a:-d /s "%dirA%" 2^>NUL') do if exist "%dirB%%%~nxI" echo %%~nxI does exist in "%dirB%" 
:eof
```

Comment: do you want to just check the filename or the partial path as well?

Comment: edited question, would be nice to show in which folder/sub-folder the file was found (if found) but that is less important as just knowing which files are duplicated between the two given directories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for putting me on the correct track :-) Code now works

```
:bof
    @echo off
    cls
    setlocal
:init
    set dirA=X:\tst\pfsrc\
    set dirB=X:\tst\cbsrc\
    if not exist "%dirA%" echo dirA not found & goto :EOF
    if not exist "%dirB%" echo dirB not found & goto :EOF
    for /f "delims=" %%I in ('dir /b /a:-d /s "%dirA%" 2^>NUL') do for /r "%dirB%" %%d in (%%~nxI) do if exist "%%d" echo %%d
:eof
```

Answer (score 1):

this excerpt will try to find `%%a` in all dirs of `%dirB%` recursively

```
for /d /r %%d in (%dirB%\*) do (
  if exist "%%d\%%~nxa" echo %%d\%%~nxa
)
```

Comment: I am playing with this a bit, but there seems to be a small bug as it adds the pathname it searches as well as the pathname of dir.  value of %%d --> X:\tst\cbsrc\dcr\sys\CVS\X:\tst\cbsrc\

Comment: for /f "delims=" %%I in ('dir /b /a:-d /s "%dirA%" 2^>NUL') do for /r %%d in (%dirB%) do if exist "%%~nxI" echo %%d " - " %%~nxI   <-- This line returns a echo for a file found (but it does it for every subfolder and only when the file is in the main folder (does not work if file in sub-folder)

Comment: +1 for putting me on right track :-) Got the code to work now